# Git not pushing everything

Tags: git, github

I worked on a project locally. I decided to take the time and backup everything using GitHub.

My project is about 2GB large in total. I initialised git, logged in etc and successfully committed and pushed.

The entire project on git is about 5MB, so not all files have been uploaded.
What is going on? How can I push everything to git?

Edit

I did:

Went online to GitHub and created a new repo:

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin LINK.git
git push -u origin master
```

What I suspect:
It used to be a git project. I removed .git and worked on it offline. I didn't fork it etc. It's so much modified and I added so much that it has literally nothing to do with the original anymore.

I removed with git remote rm origin and rm -rf .git. I suspect problem originating from this maybe

Comment: Are you sure you staged all the files you need backing up? Also check your .gitignore (if you have one) file isn’t excluding file types

Comment: Clone the project somewhere else.  Inspect it to see what is missing.  You probably didn't commit everything.

Comment: As the others mentioned probably not everything was commited. Try `git status` on your terminal to see if you can get more information about the current state.

Comment: Git add --all should add all tho right?

Comment: @dev Nop, very much depends on your global `~/.gitconfig`, especially if it configures global ignore rules.